# Is there any benefit of a Vapour-barrier with gaps?

Tags: vapor-barrier

I'm installing fiberglass insulation to the floor of a cold loft.  I've heard it is best to lay a vapour barrier first.

The trouble is that it is a 1960's house with poor access. There is no chance that I will be able to get everywhere and form a proper seal.

Is there benefit to laying a vapour barrier with some gaps, or is that a complete waste?

(In the UK)

Comment: What's under the loft that makes the floor cold?  And I assume the loft is going to be used as a living space?

Comment: Also, you generally want the vapor barrier on the warm side of the floor, or wall.

Comment: Use Cellulose insulation, which is very good at moisture management and reducing airflow within the insulation material.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave gaps then you are wasting your time and money.

Arrange to seal the vapour barrier properly.